# RPM Newrelic metric names for browser page load time

Tags: analytics, metrics, newrelic

In the Dashboard of NewRelic RPM I can see a chart named "Browser page load time".

[image]

It contains 4 values, **what are the metric names for this chart ?**

I got a response from their support team:

```
EndUser/average_app_without_queue_time
EndUser/average_network_time
EndUser/average_page_rendering_time
EndUser/RB/average_dom_content_load_time
```

But:

the **EndUser/** endpoint didn't specify the **average_app_without_queue_time** metric.

the **EndUser/** endpoint didn't specify the **average_page_rendering_time** metric.

So I miss two metrics of the above four...

I want simply fetch the data represented in the above chart in JSON format via their API.

Answer (score 0):

Those two metrics, “**EndUser/average_app_without_queue_time**” and “**EndUser/average_page_rendering_time**”, and not standalone metrics like the other two, they are calculated metrics.  This means that they are not going to be available directly from the API and that instead you will need to pull down their constituent parts and perform the calculation.  Here are the two formulas:

```
average_app_without_queue_time = ("EndUser".total_app_time - "EndUser/RB".total_queue_time) / "EndUser".call_count
```

and

```
average_page_rendering_time = "EndUser".average_fe_response_time - "EndUser/RB".average_dom_content_load_time
```